# Add content from object to JQUERY-CONFIRM

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, ecmascript-6, jquery-confirm

I have an object and want to add the details of that to the content of [JQUERY-CONFIRM](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/).

This is my code:

```js
const obj = {
  'alphabets':['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr'],
  'colors':['red', 'blue', 'purple']
}

$.dialog({
 title: 'Test',
 columnClass: 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-6',
 content: function() {
  for (let key in obj) {
   return `<h3 class='float-left'>${key}</h3>
      <ul class='float-left'>
       <li class='float-left'>${obj[key]}</li>
      </ul>
      `;
  }
 },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Why am I only getting the first key-value in my content and also why aren't they listing out in the list but showing up as comma-separated values?

Comment: Think about what `return` means.

Comment: @Quentin, I am getting an empty space if I remove the return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop through the object keys but always return at the first iteration.

You could use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map all the `obj` key/value pairs to the HTML strings and then [.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(mapToHtml).join('')
```

`colors` and `alphabets` were displayed as comma-separated values because you put the entire array into one `<li>` element: `<li class='float-left'>${obj[key]}</li>`. To create multiple `<li>` elements you need to map each element of the array to a new `<li>`:

```
const list = obj[key].map(li => `<li class='float-left'>${li}</li>`).join('');
```

```js
const obj = {
  'alphabets':['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr'],
  'colors':['red', 'blue', 'purple']
}

const mapToHtml = key => {
    const list = obj[key].map(li => `<li class='float-left'>${li}</li>`).join('');
    return `<h3 class='float-left'>${key}</h3><ul class='float-left'>${list}</ul>`;
}

$.dialog({
    title: 'Test',
    columnClass: 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-6',
    content: () => Object.keys(obj).map(mapToHtml).join('')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. What about `['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr'],`. This is supposed to be a list

Comment: @nb_nb_nb please see my update. I've created the `mapToHtml` function for readability